# Ошибка при добавлении записи в пустую таблицу

Tags: android, android-sqlite

У меня есть EditText и Array checkedTextView (array), из которого пользователь выбирает нужные строки и помечает. Код ниже обрабатывает какие поля выбрал пользователь и отправляет их на запись в таблицу

```
EditText et=findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName2);
for (int i=0;i<array.size();i++)
{
    if( array.get(i).isChecked())
    {
        MyDatabaseHelper myDB1 = new MyDatabaseHelper(this);
        String name=array.get(i).getText().toString().trim();
        **myDB1.add_compani(et.getText().toString().trim(),name);**
    }
}
```

Данный метод делает запись, но я не могу понять почему выводит сообщение об ошибке("Failed"), так как аналогичный метод для другой таблицы работает без проблем

```
void add_compani(String name,String name_f) {
    SQLiteDatabase db1 = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv1 = new ContentValues();
    cv1.put("name_c", name);
    cv1.put("name_founders", name_f);
    long result = db1.insert("compani", null, cv1);
    if (result == -1) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else
        Toast.makeText(context, "Added Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Возможно ошибка на моменте создания таблицы. Для работы с бд использую собственный экземпляр класса SQLiteOpenHelper

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String query=
            "CREATE TABLE founders" +
                    " ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
                    "name TEXT );";

    db.execSQL(query);
    String q2="CREATE TABLE compani" +
                     " ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
                     "name_c TEXT, "+
                     "name_founders TEXT );";
    db.execSQL(q2);
}
```

Пожалуйста помогите!

Comment: Попробуйте использовать метод [`insertOrThrow`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#insertOrThrow(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) вместо `insert`, тогда вы получите больше информации об ошибке. Полученный стектрейс [приложите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1478955/edit) в вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Очень странно, что фиксится новым эмулятором
При таком раскладе делать новые таблицы на устройства накладно....
Хотя может с реальными девайсами дела обстоят намного лучше